# Angular JS installation on netbeans

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, netbeans-7

I installed Angular JS plugin on my netbeans 7 which works fine but I am unable to get the drop down directive suggestion for angular JS like `ng-app, ng-model="name"` etc. In fact, the HTML page shows warning `Attribute "ng-app" not allowed on element "html" at this point.`

I used http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40296 to install plugin, below is what I did in my index.html:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="js/angular-0.9.19.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello {{1+2}} </h1>
```

Answer (score 13):

Speaking for the NetBeans team, the truth is that we would like to improve the AngularJS support going forward. In NetBeans 7.3, you are right that you will get a warning on attributes like ng-app, ng-model etc. You can get rid of this error using the hint on the first line: "Disable HTML error checking for this file". We are working on support for AngularJS and other frameworks as we speak, please follow the NetBeans Web Client blog at https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeanswebclient/ to get updates on new features coming in the next release.

Comment: Thanks for all your work. I've been using Netbeans for over 10 years and love it as much as I did when I first started!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `data-` prefix : " As Angular's attributes, at least ng-app
etc. can be replaced with data-ng-app which will be valid for IDE and AngularJS
as well" https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=225462

Comment: +1 This is very good advice, and there is nothing for the Netbeans team to do if users follow html5 standards. Good work on Angular sticking to standards.